# 415 unsupported media type for sending json object in ajax call Spring mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am sending  json object to spring mvc controller from ajax call.

Here is my json object which i am sending to controller.

```
 [{"id":"7","priority":"8","startTime":"2015-09-23 01:01:00.0"}]
```

My ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            url : 'save.web',
            datatype:'json',
            type: "post", 
            data: "data="+JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
            success:function(data){

        }
```

my controller

```
 RequestMapping(value = "save.web", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public   String save( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  
response,@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputParameter, 
         @RequestParam("data")  String ja) {
    System.out.println("--------------Entered Save-----------");
     return "menu"
 }
```

i tried using @requestBody annotation Instead of @requestParam. I tried Setting Headers and used Consumes in RequestMapping Still i am getting POST http://localhost:8089/campaignManager/save.web 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
 Error.

please let me know the solution. i tried lot

Answer (score 4):

I resolved my error.(415 Error)

I shd remove @RequestBody from my controller..

Comment: then how did you map your form data to back end?

Comment: If using a Rest API, like .NET Core, removing the [FromBody] attribute in the controller method parameters worked for me.  e.g. Create([FromBody]  Foo foo) to Create(Foo foo)

Answer (score 3):

The server is sending the 415 due to the content media type in the request is not the one expected by the server.

add the contentType to request header like: `contentType: "application/json"`

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'save.web',
    datatype:'json',
    type: "post", 
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "data="+JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
    success:function(data){
    }
```

Comment: i added contentType: "application/json", in ajax call but still same error persists..

Comment: change  data: "data="+JSON.stringify(jsonArray) to data:JSON.stringify(jsonArray)   . output shoul look like this $.ajax({
    url : 'save.web',
    datatype:'json',
    type: "post", 
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
    success:function(data){
    }

Comment: I tried changing daa:Json.stringify(jsonArray).. Still the error persists

Comment: ARe you getting the same error 415 or some different one

Comment: @DhaneeshNair  the addition of `contentType: "application/json"` worked for me. I was getting `415` before and data as expected after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Include jackson-binding.jar in your classpath.

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.11</version>
</dependency>

Also set content-type="application-json" in request-header
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 415 error is because of the return type and not the request type. ajax doesn't support chunked data which could be one of the default response you are getting from service. This is one of the default response you get from new version web-api. Only solution is to use XmlHttpRequest.