# How receive a list of JavaScript objects in a List<Object> in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, arrays, ajax, spring, list

I was reading a lot but I don't know what is the error in my code. I hope you can help me. Regards.

Model: RenglonFacturaDTO(With his getters/setters)

```
public class RenglonFacturaDTO implements Comparable<RenglonFacturaDTO>{

   private Integer idfact;
   private Long idrenglon;
   private Integer idremito;
   private Float cant;
   private String descripadic;
   private Double precio;
   private Double subtotal;
}
```

This is the list of objects that i send via ajax to controller

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    
       var cliente = $('.id').data('id');
       var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
       var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content"); 
       var listado = [{}];
      

      $('#generar').click(function(){

         cliente = $('#idcliente').data('id');
    
         $('.renglon').each(function(){
        
             elem = $(this);    
        
             cant = elem.find('.cant').val();
             precio = elem.find('.precio').val();
             descripadic = elem.find('.descripadic').val();
             idremito = elem.find('.idremito').text();
             idrenglon = elem.data('idrenglon');
             idfact = $('#factura').data('idfact');
             subtotal = cant * precio;
        
             listado.push({"cant": parseFloat(cant),"precio": precio ,"descripadic":descripadic,"subtotal":subtotal ,"idremito":idremito ,"idrenglon":idrenglon , "idfact":idfact});
        
         });

       $.ajax({
          "type":"post",
          "url":"agregarRenglonesFactura",
          "dataType": 'json',
          "cache": false,
          "data": {"listado": listado},
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // here it is
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
          }
        
         });
     });
 });
</script>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/agregarRenglonesFactura", method= RequestMethod.POST) 
public String redAgregarRenglonFactura(@ModelAttribute ArrayList<RenglonFacturaDTO> renglonesfacturadto) throws Exception{
    
        Iterator<RenglonFacturaDTO> it = renglonesfacturadto.iterator();
        
        while(it.hasNext()){
        
            RenglonFacturaDTO renglonfacturadto = it.next();
        
        System.out.println("***************AGREGAR RENGLON*******************IDRENGLONREMITO: " + renglonfacturadto.getIdrenglon() + " CANTIDAD: " + renglonfacturadto.getCant());
        }
        
        return ("TAMAÑO LISTA: " + renglonesfacturadto.size());
}
```

this is the error:

```
 Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
Invalid property 'listado[10][cant]' of bean class [ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ListadoRenglonesFacturaDTO]:
Property referenced in indexed property path 'listado[10][cant]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.RenglonFacturaDTO@67e12cdf]] con causa raíz
```

This is the array that i send via post

```
listado[0][cant]15
listado[0][descripadic]
listado[0][idfact]12
listado[0][idremito]9
listado[0][idrenglon]36
listado[0][precio]135
listado[0][subtotal]2025
listado[1][cant]15
listado[1][descripadic]
listado[1][idfact]12
listado[1][idremito]9l
istado[1][idrenglon]36
listado[1][precio]135
listado[1][subtotal]2025
listado[2][cant]15
listado[2][descripadic]
listado[2][idfact]12
listado[2][idremito]9
listado[2][idrenglon]36
listado[2][precio]135
listado[2][subtotal]2025
```

Comment: You should create a proper JSON something like below:-
[]

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery ajax requests, especially if you're sending a list, you want to use JSON.stringify().

```
"data": JSON.stringify({ 'listado': listado }),
```

As a side note, you're also passing a null value with your list because of the way it's instantiated.  You could just write

```
var listado = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I try this but nothing happen, it works without exceptions but the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a proper JSON before posting it to controller, something like below

> [
>     { "cant": 15,
>     ...
>     }
>   ]

And your controller RequestMapping should look like below:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/agregarRenglonesFactura", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public String  
redAgregarRenglonFactura(@RequestBody ArrayList<RenglonFacturaDTO> 
renglonesfacturadto) throws Exception{}
```

Comment: If i send via post a json array, i get: The server rejected this requirement because the required entity is in a format not supported by the required resource for the required method.

if also, I add "headers": {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
           },
to the jquery ajax, i get the following: The requirement sent by the customer was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Change your ajax call to 
 "data": listado

Comment: It is the same, i get Http 415, but i change @ModelAttribute to @RequestParam("listado) List<String> and i get the following:
{"listado":[{"idfact":12
"idrenglon":22
"idremito":9
"cant":1
"descripadic":""
"precio":135
"subtotal":135}
{"idfact":12
"idrenglon":23
"idremito":9
"cant":2
"descripadic":""
"precio":65
"subtotal":130}
{"idfact":12
"idrenglon":24
"idremito":9
"cant":3
"descripadic":""
"precio":450
"subtotal":1350}
]}

but i don't know how can bind with a collection of type RenglonFacturaDTO.

Comment: 415 is unsupported media type, refer this SO post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664316/415-unsupported-media-type-for-sending-json-object-in-ajax-call-spring-mvc